# Is there a way to increase the size of the Caja file selector thumbnails?

Tags: thunderbird, mate, ubuntu-mate, caja

Hopefully the title makes sense.

All I need to know is if there is a way to make the thumbnails/image previews bigger as on a laptop screen they are pretty hard to see.

[image]

Comment: I am not so familiar with this desktop but my first thoughts are, press ctrl and + or ctrl + shift and + to zoom in.

Comment: @MarkKirby Tried that all first, unfortunately there's no apparent way to zoom that I know of.

Comment: does [this Q&A](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/mate-panel-icon-sizes-menu-button-size/11909) from Mate Community help?

Comment: After reading through I think that nothing from there really seems like it could apply well to this since it's all tray and bar icon related

Comment: It is very likely that it is hardcoded in GtkFileChooser https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.FileChooser.set_preview_widget.html and there is no way to customize it even using CSS .

Comment: Damn, thats a shame, I guess the previews on the side panel are good enough then